# Change the user identity in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following scenario:

On one PC I have SQL db where the owner is local user e.g. \xyz. This db has a lot of users and they all are domain user. Now I have to make a copy of the db on another PC. I'm planning to backup it up and restore on the second computer. I think that domain users will be OK but local user \xyz likely will not be OK because  is different and etc.

My question is: how could I change it and make \xyz valid on the second PC? Could I delete this user and create a new one with correct  and likely assign ownership and roles it had on the first PC?

I have to do this procedure on 5 PC and I'm thinking of a way to save time  and it came to my mind that backup/restore would be the best and simple approach ... but I am concern about local user.

Thanks

Comment: All login creation and permission assignments are scriptable, just check MSDN for the syntax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

When you restore a db from one server to another, you may have "orphaned" database users.  You'll need to [re-map the db user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) to an existing (or new) server login.  For instance:

```
ALTER USER \xyz
WITH LOGIN = loginName
```

Comment: Well ... based on the link you provided I found this:
"You can change the name of a user who is mapped to a Windows login or group only when the SID of the new user name matches the SID that is recorded in the database."
In my case SID will be different and that might be a problem IMO.
I have another suggestion: could I change the name of DB owner now from local user to domain user. In that case I should not care when restore it on another computer.
How could I change current owner to another user name?
Thanks

Comment: I think I misread your question.  Sorry about that.  Just to be sure we're on the same page, a "user" is an object within a database.  A "login" is an object within the sql server.  The database owner is a "login".  After restoring a db, if you need to change the db owner, use stored proc `sp_changedbowner`.  The above info about re-mapping orphaned db users may still be relevant to your situation, though.  If you wan't to change a "user" name, re-mapping the user to an existing (or new) server login will re-synch the SID's.  Then you can rename the "user".